# What string equivalence logic is Chrome using here?

Tags: browser, unicode, string-comparison

When you search for the string `۱` in web browsers (at least Chrome and Safari, but not Firefox), it will tell you it matches the string `1`.  I asked a rather dumb "What's the point?" kind of question about this [on Superuser](https://superuser.com/questions/1690228/what-is-the-point-of-extended-digits-like-%DB%B1), and frankly I don't think I came up with a good answer.

After digging a bit deeper into unicode, I'm even more curious.  **What is the mechanism behind Chrome's string equivalence here?**

Here are a few things I think Chrome is **NOT** doing:

1. Fallback characters.  Arabic-Indic characters are nowhere on the [fallback character chart](https://unicode-org.github.io/cldr-staging/charts/37/supplemental/character_fallback_substitutions.html), and neither are most of the numeral characters from other scripts.  Plus, character equivalence is a separate matter from font display.
2. Normalized comparison.  [Normalization](https://unicode.org/faq/normalization.html) is a tool unicode provides for string comparison.  It seems intended for cases where characters are visually similar but constructed differently, so I didn't think this was a likely candidate, but it's a surprisingly deep topic by itself, so I wouldn't be surprised if I missed something here. I checked using Python 3.8 how `۱` and `1` compare:

```
>>> "۱" == "1"
False
>>> unicodedata.normalize("NFD","۱").encode("utf-8")
b'\xdb\xb1'
>>> unicodedata.normalize("NFD","1").encode("utf-8")
b'1'
```

3. Any other unicode-defined mapping. After looking for a while, I came to agree with [Wikipedia's claim](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Numerals_in_Unicode#Hindu%E2%80%93Arabic_numerals) that

> ...there is no mapping between the various related digits

Something Chrome **might** be doing:

1. Numerical equivalence. Unicode provides a `Numeric_Value` as one of [the properties](https://unicode.org/reports/tr44/#Default_Values_Table) for each code point.  I suppose you could build your own equivalence table from the numeric values of unicode points. As an example in python, you can get the numeric value of unicode, though you can't easily use non-ascii numerals in arithmetic:

```
>>> unicodedata.numeric("۱")
1.0
>>> unicodedata.numeric("1")
1.0
>>> 1 == ۱
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    1 == ۱
         ^
SyntaxError: invalid character in identifier
```

As a bonus, I'd love to know of other software that has the same equivalence logic.  So far, it's just Chrome and Safari.  Even Google's other in-browser tools like Docs don't support it.